# How to prevent user from inputting two of the same numbers

Tags: python

So I'm working on my lottery code in my free time, and I have come across a minor issue.

I want to prevent the user from entering two of the same numbers in their lottery draw numbers i.e I don't want user picking the number 1 twice.

Everything else works fine.

Here is my entire code:

```
import random
lotteryNumbers = []



print("Welcome to your new Lotto service")


lotterydrawfile = open("lotterydrawfile.txt","w")
for i in range (6):
    number = random.randint(1,60)
    lotterydrawfile.write(str(number) + " ")


lotterydrawfile.close()


userentryfile = open("userentryfile.txt","w")
for i in range (6):
    number = input("Enter a number between 0 and 60. Numbers must not be in word format")
    for i in range (1000):
        if number < "0" or number > "60":
            print("Your number needs to be between 0 and 60")
            number = input("Enter a number between 0 and 60")

    print(str(number))
    userentryfile.write(str(number) + " ")
userentryfile.close()


userlottonumbers = open("userentryfile.txt").read()

usernumber = []
number_string = ""
for i in userlottonumbers:
    number_string = number_string + str(i)

    if str(i) == " ":
        usernumber.append(number_string)
        number_string = ""
print("Your numbers are " + str(usernumber))


lotterydraw = open("lotterydrawfile.txt").read()
number_string1 = ""
lottodraw = []
for j in lotterydraw:
    number_string1 = number_string1 + str(j)

    if str(j) == " ":
        lottodraw.append(number_string1)
        number_string1 = ""

print("The lotto draw was " + str(lottodraw))

same = 0
for i in usernumber:

    for j in lottodraw:

        if i == j:
            same =same + 1

prize = same * 100

if same == 6:
    prize = 10000000
print("You won £" + str(prize))
```

The improvement that I want to make is where the line begins:

```
    userentryfile = open("userentryfile.txt","w")
for i in range (6):
    number = input("Enter a number between 0 and 60. Numbers must not be in word format")
    for i in range (1000):
if number < "0" or number > "60":
        print("Your number needs to be between 0 and 60")
        number = input("Enter a number between 0 and 60")
```

But underneath, where I want the user to stop inputting two of the same numbers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a `set()` to store the numbers, then loop on the size of the set `len(set_name)`.  With sets, duplicates are ignored.

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't be using the counter 'i' twice to count in nested loops.  But why is that for i in range (1000) there anyway?

Comment: @emmalg - I'm new to python so i'm learning as I go along

Comment: @1ndy123, We've all been there! I just meant, you should give each nested loop a different counter, for i, for j, for k... But I did wonder what is the purpose of that loop?  Why did you think it was needed?  You could change it to a different letter, but what did you want it to be counting?

Comment: How many numbers is the user expected to enter?

Comment: @kbball - 6 numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you really want a while loop and store the numbers as they are picked, like this:

```
    numbers = []
    while len(numbers) < 6:
    number = input("Enter a number between 0 and 60. Numbers must not be in word format")
    if not number.isdigit():
      print("Your number is not in number format")
    elif float(number) < 0 or float(number) > 60:
      print("Your number needs to be between 0 and 60")
    elif number in numbers:
      print("You already picked that number")
    else:
      numbers.append(number)
```

This was tested here: https://repl.it/NJWE/2

Comment: That works perfectly fine, but I'm testing all possible tests i.e null field test. Whenever i type a letter in, not a number, I get the error "line 22, in <module>
    number = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 60. Numbers must not be in word format"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'q'

Comment: @1ndy123 ok I added a check to make sure a number is entered

Answer (score 1):

Keep the numbers that the user inputs in a list and test to see if the most recent input is already in that list:

```
numbers = []

if number not in numbers:
    numbers.append(number)
else:
    # "each number must be unique..."
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a data type in python called a set. Everything that is put into a set must be unique. There can only be one of each thing in a set at a time. The following code should also catch most if not all the edge cases that would cause problems for you in the future. It makes sure the users input really is a number, really is between 0 and 60, has not been picked before, and and will get exactly 6 numbers from the user.

```
def get_user_numbers(number_of_guesses):

    # a set can only have one element with the any given value
    users_numbers = set()

    # used to keep the while loop going until you have all the information you want.
    got_all_numbers = False
    while not got_all_numbers:

        # tries to get input from the user. The except statement will be hit if the
        # user gives you something other than a whole number.
        try:
            current_number = int(raw_input("Enter a number between 0 and 60"))
        except ValueError:
            print 'Please enter a number'

        # Checks to make sure the number is in the range you want it to be.
        if current_number < 0 or current_number > 60:
            print 'Please pick a number between 0 and 60.'
        # Checks to see if the number has already been used.
        elif current_number in users_numbers:
            print 'Please pick a number that you have not already used'
        # if everything else if correct it will add the users number to the set.
        else:
            users_numbers.add(current_number)
        # Checks to make sure the set still has less than 6 numbers in it. If it
        # does then the while loop will keep going until there are 6 guesses
        if len(users_numbers) == number_of_guesses:
            got_all_numbers = True
        elif len(users_numbers) > number_of_guesses:
            # There is a big problem... The user managed to give you more guesses
            # than you are asking for! The program should exit or you should start
            #  over with blank guesses
            raise ValueError
        # If you wanted to you could print out all of the users guesses here so they
        # can see what they have already tried

    return users_numbers


print get_user_numbers(6)
```

To use this function in your program you can simply put the function call at the top of your file, then use the function call in the code you have already written. Here is an example of what your code will look like:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import random


def get_user_numbers(number_of_guesses):
    users_numbers = list()
    got_all_numbers = False
    while not got_all_numbers:
        try:
            current_number = int(raw_input("Enter a number between 0 and 60:  "))
        except ValueError:
            print 'Please enter a number'
        else:
            if current_number < 0 or current_number > 60:
                print 'Please pick a number between 0 and 60.'
            elif current_number in users_numbers:
                print 'Please pick a number that you have not already used'
            else:
                users_numbers.append(current_number)
            if len(users_numbers) == number_of_guesses:
                got_all_numbers = True
            elif len(users_numbers) > number_of_guesses:
                raise ValueError
    user_numbers_string = ' '.join(str(guess) for guess in users_numbers)
    return user_numbers_string


lotteryNumbers = []

print("Welcome to your new Lotto service")

lotterydrawfile = open("lotterydrawfile.txt", "w")
for i in range(6):
    number = random.randint(1, 60)
    lotterydrawfile.write(str(number) + " ")

lotterydrawfile.close()

# Here is where you call the function that is at the top of the file 
userlottonumbers = get_user_numbers(6)

usernumber = []
number_string = ""
for i in userlottonumbers:
    number_string = number_string + str(i)

    if str(i) == " ":
        usernumber.append(number_string)
        number_string = ""
print("Your numbers are " + str(usernumber))

lotterydraw = open("lotterydrawfile.txt").read()
number_string1 = ""
lottodraw = []
for j in lotterydraw:
    number_string1 = number_string1 + str(j)

    if str(j) == " ":
        lottodraw.append(number_string1)
        number_string1 = ""

print("The lotto draw was " + str(lottodraw))

same = 0
for i in usernumber:

    for j in lottodraw:

        if i == j:
            same = same + 1

prize = same * 100

if same == 6:
    prize = 10000000
print("You won £" + str(prize))
```

Comment: do i replace the code 'for i in range 6' etc with the code above?

Comment: I added an example of how to use it in your code at the bottom of my answer.